# How to define the width and row/cell format of an npoi word table

Tags: c#, ms-word, apache-poi, npoi

I'm creating a word file containing a table using NPOI library.
How can I set the table's width and the row/cell formatting?

In POI library they say you must use getCTTbl and other method/classes that I can't find in NPOI.

Answer (score 9):

//XWPFTable table = doc.CreateTable(2, 4);

```
table.Width = 5000;  

table.SetColumnWidth(0, 1000);
table.SetColumnWidth(1, 1500);
table.SetColumnWidth(2, 1000);
table.SetColumnWidth(3, 1500);
```